# "Stealing" a question improvement

Tags: bug, questions, editing

I was suggested to approve the question edit performed by someone else, and while I found the edits quite reasonable, couple tags were missing, so I added them, and this automatically rendered the whole edit as mine, which is both inaccurate and not cool. :-)

Next time I'll approve first and then add tags/my own edits, but — can this be changed by the community or this is just a bad UX of SE itself?

Or, else, should I report it as a bug or an erroneous site behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not *quite* true. You approved the original edit and automatically added an additional edit to the edit log.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/85815/revisions

[image]

From an audit trail point of view then everything is accounted for. [They get their credit for a successful edit](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/74013/josip-ivic?tab=reputation), as do you. Just that yours came more recently so it shows on the question itself that it was recently edited by you.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the clarification. I thought the whole edit got assigned to me.